# Create solr index without repeating

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

If I want to make an index that produces suggestions with the following possibilities

Category

CategorySynonyms

Category + feature

CategorySynonyms + feature

Do I have to first select all Categories and make documents from all of them.
Then select all CategorySynonyms and make documents from them.
Them select All categories joined with feature and make documents from them
And then all CategorySynonyms joined with feature and then make documents form them.

Or is there a way to index Category one time, CategorySynonyms and Feature one time with out repeating in documents multiple times?

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what method you are actually using for indexing?

Comment: Im using dataimporthandler, so its sql-queries in solr-entities that generates the documents.

Comment: Can you post your schemal.xml?

Comment: The schema just contains field types, i have not tryed to solve the solution yet, i need to know if this approach is viable first and how to implement the design.